# How to make IF statement in Javascript based on the json result in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Well, sorry for my bad grammar, but any help will be much appreciated..

Ok, here I'm trying to encode string by using json inside PHP then using JavaScript to read the `json` string. It will have 2 cases here. 
The first one is, the application will running normally, so does the encode. The json string will be like this :

```
{"employee":
[{"id":"1","firstName":"aaa","lastName":"abc","timeIn":"08:00:00","timeOut":"17:00:00"},
{"id":"2","firstName":"bbb","lastName":"def","timeIn":"08:00:00","timeOut":"16:45:00"}]}
```

and the second one is, the PHP can't read the MySQL database, so in PHP the json encode will be like this :

```
{"errorProcess":{"text":SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. }}
```

The question is, in JavaScript how can I make an `IF statement` in JavaScript  based on the result string in `json`?
Maybe it will be like this, but I don't know how to write it in JavaScript.

```
IF (in json string has employee){then result}
else if(in json string has errorProcess){then result}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you parsing json in javascript? You need to turn it into a javascript object first

Answer (score 3):

You can check for errorProcess key using

```
if(json.hasOwnProperty('errorProcess')){
   //do struff
}
```

Comment: I was gonna write an answer with `typeof json.errorProcess != 'undefined'` but this seems way more elegant

Answer (score 1):

JSON keys and values are accessed using dot (.) notation in Javascript.  Assuming you already have the JSON as an object (not a string), you can simply write

```
if (json.employee) {
  // do something
}
else if (json.error) {
  // do something else
}
```

where `json` is a variable referencing your returned JSON from the php.

If your JSON is still in string format, you need to parse it into an object.  This can be done with the built in `JSON` object.

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonAsString);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to [parese JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) like this

```
var jsonObject= jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsonObj);

if(jsonObject.hasOwnProperty('employee')){
// Add your code

}else if(jsonObject.hasOwnProperty('errorProcess')){
// Add your code
}
```